# Opacity on just jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I want to set the jumbotron to 0.5 opacity.

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
         <table id="white" class="table table-condensed" id="table">
           <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>En</td>
             <th>1</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>To</td>
            <th>2</th>
           </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to do this on just the jumbotron and not the table?

Comment: Whats the `CSS` behind this? if its the background you want opacity on then yes using `rgba`.

Comment: you can use rgba() for the background: http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html

Comment: But if you tell what is your purpose we will try to help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use RGBa

```
.jumbotron {
   background: rgb(200, 54, 54); /* This is for ie8 and below */
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); 
}
```

Last value on the second line (0.5) is the opacity.

For clarity this won't work on ie8 or below as rgba is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

Give jumbotron an ID and set that ID to opacity via the `rgba` property in the `CSS`.

**CSS:**

```
#jumbo {
    /* IE8 and below */
    background: rgb(200, 54, 54);
    /* all other browsers */
    background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
}
#white {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo">
    <table id="white" class="table table-condensed" id="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>En</td>
                <th>1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>To</td>
                <th>2</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Set the opacity via `rgba` of the child elements back to opaque.

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mstnorris/Wq56V/)

Comment: Why would you need to give it an ID? And not just use the class already there. Also setting the opacity on this would affect anything inside.

Comment: Giving it an ID means you can target that one directly. You can just set the opacity back to opaque for the child elements.

Comment: Using a class also means that you can target that one directly, as long as you don't have another on the page... What do you mean `opacity back`? You mean the background. In your answer you said it like using `opacity: 0.5;` your code however it using `rgba`. You should make this clearer in your answer. Also your update doesn't reflect in your code at all.

Comment: You did? That looks so messy, I didn't even bother looking at it properly. Try to keep code to a minimum (unless all the other code is needed, in this case its not).

Comment: No disrespect @Ruddy but this website is all about learning. For the OP, they are familiar with what is going on so that they can extract what they need and the JSFiddle is exactly that. For someone else who finds this page, they can see the entire solution in context.

Comment: In context of what? A basic html page layout? The only thing that is needed is the relevant code. I understand where you are coming from but it looks too messy and confusing for such a simple answer. If you don't want to take my advice then by all means don't.

Comment: I have edited your answer for you, just to show you how neat it can be. If you feel this has affected your answer, please just roll it back to your last edit. Also just to add on to your answer, you do not need to set an opacity on the table inside as using `rgba` doesn't affect the child elements (the point of the question and answers). [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Wq56V/1/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/s9TXb/)

CSS opacity is defined by the parent and is a hierarchical property, so any children inherit/are subjected to their parents opacity.

The way you can accomplish varying levels of opacity for nested elements is to set any respective **color** properties using **rgba** values, this wont however work for things like background images etc (unless in `img` tags in which case they can be targeted seperately)

[**More on RGBa from MDN**](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/color_value.html#RGBa_%28red-green-blue-alpha%29_rgba%28R.2CG.2CB.2Ca%29)

> RGBa .. Extends the RGB color model to include "alpha" to allow
>   specification of the opacity of a color. a means opacity:
>   0=transparent; 1=opaque;